# Function to get SheetName in Cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am using this function to enter the sheetname in a cell if cell A1 is not blank. The problem is, when I try to update all sheets with this formula at once, each time I recalculate it renames the cells in ALL sheets to the active sheetname. How can I apply this to a column in ALL sheets so it shows 'that' sheetname?

```
Function SheetName()
 SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
End Function
```

Call using:

```
=IF(A2="","",SheetName())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Application.Caller`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193687):

```
Function SheetName()
    SheetName = Application.Caller.Parent.Name
End Function
```

---

Alternative with Excel Formula (from https://exceljet.net/formula/get-sheet-name-only):

```
= MID(CELL("filename", A1), FIND("]", CELL("filename", A1)) + 1, 255)
```